Width and height changes in mobile view
When I make my screen smaller, my width and height changes and changes the whole layout of the page. But when it is bigger it works just as fine, I do not know what is causing it but to debug I am using the browser's elements.

Here is the code that I am using:
<div className='h-full w-full text-white gap-y-10 flex flex-col'>
  <p className='text-white text-3xl'>All projects.</p>
  <table className="text-sm">
    <thead className='text-gray-500 py-10'>
      <tr className="text-left">
        <th className="pl-[2rem] p-[1rem]">Date</th>
        <th className="">Title</th>
        <th className="">Where</th>
        <th className="">Built With</th>
        <th className="pr-[2rem] p-[1rem]">Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody className="">
      {allProjectsData && allProjectsData.map((project) => (
        <tr key={project.githubUrl} className="py-10 hover:bg-[#1e293b]">
          <td className="rounded-l-lg  pl-[2rem] p-[10px] text-left py-5 text-green-500 whitespace-normal break-words">{project.date}</td>
          <td className="p-[1rem] text-left py-5 font-extrabold">{project.title}</td>
          <td className="p-[1rem] text-left py-5 font-extrabold">{project.madeAt ? project.madeAt : "-" }</td>
          <td className="flex flex-wrap items-center p-[1rem] text-left py-5 font-gray-500 text-xs whitespace-normal break-words">
            {project.technologies.map((technology, i) => (
              <span key={i}>{technology}{''}{i !== technology.length - 1 && <span className="font-extrabold mx-[5px]">&middot;</span>}</span>
            ))}
          </td>
          <td className="rounded-r-lg pr-[2rem] p-[1rem]">
            <div className="flex gap-x-2">
              <Link href={project.githubUrl}>
                <AiOutlineExport />
              </Link>
              {project.productionUrl && <Link href={project.productionUrl}><IoMdBrowsers /></Link>}
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <Link className="text-sm text-green-500 underline underline-offset-8  text-center hover:text-white" href='/'>
    Back to the home page
  </Link>
</div>


It seems to be that the <table> is overflowing horizontally, since it can't "shrink" in width any more with narrower viewports. You could look at a different layout for narrower viewports or have a horizontally scrolling wrapper element to deal with this overflow.
